# Data comparison between source and target (need count of matched and mismatched records)

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, count

I created a data comparison sheet using Pyspark (Src Minus Target and populated the result in a separate Excel sheet). Now I want to get the count of each column's matched and unmatched records in the same Excel workbook under a separate sheet. Does anyone have any ideas for how to implement this?

**Data Compared Output**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

```py
# Comparison
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

src.equals(tgt)
comparison_values = src.values == tgt.values

print(comparison_values)

rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    src.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(src.iloc[item[0], item[1]], tgt.iloc[item[0], item[1]])
    src.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```